# Definition of “pooled sovereignty”

Tags: european-union

What does pooled sovereignty mean?

IIUC sovereignty is pooled in the EU in the sense that supreme legislative power is vested in others offshore.

But is sovereignty pooled in, say, the UNECE automobile standards body, or the International Maritime Organisation? Or are organisations like these different. Perhaps they are  bodies that domestic governments are not bound by treaty to respect(?), and can choose to demur at any time, so sovereignty remains onshore?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things to go through from my perspective:

1. Regular people voting for a democratic body do not meet the definition of pooled sovereignty.
2. One may or may not apply pooled sovereignty to non-nationstate government (municipal collaboration, for example in geographic regions), but the other aspects apply equally.
3. If something is a democratic body, it is not pooled sovereignty (by rule 1.).
4. The pool is meaningfully part of a larger context in which the pool provides a common stance. In this case all the politics is inside the pool, it makes no sense to look outside because there is nothing.
5. There must be a form of permanence, a single-shot alliance doesn't count, but a limited period firm collaboration could.

This leads to a number of conclusions:

1. The UN (and standards bodies such as mentioned in the question) are not pooled sovereignty as they are not meaningfully part of a larger context (there are very few countries not member of the UN or the bodies). Standardization effectively leads to treaties to which the members are bound, they are rarely controversial.

   Once finalised all countries are going to be bound to the new definition of a kilogram in terms of cosmic constants, and can no longer refer to the kilogram in Paris. They are however free to use other units of measure than kilogram. Doing so is not economically advantageous for many standards.
2. The EU consists of a number of significant bodies: the European Commission, the European Council, the European Parliament and the Court of Justice of the European Union. The council is the executive branch, appointed by the council and confirmed by the parliament. The council is made up of the member countries represented by a single minister of the country (which ever they decide to send for a specific meeting). The court of justice is judicial and not that relevant either.

   The council can be seen as mainly pooled sovereignty as the link between electorate and decision making is weak. The parliament however is very much democratic. Before the Lisbon treaty the role of the parliament was somewhat limited, but this has significantly increased since the passing, with the ability to effectively veto or change laws. Overall this means to me that before Lisbon the EU was mainly pooled sovereignty, but since the Lisbon treaty the balance falls overall more on a democratic body.

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms it means being part of a larger democratic organization which gives each member greater sovereignty than it would have on its own.

For example, the UK is a member of the EU. The UK is part of the EU democracy, it has representatives and voting rights.

Japan is not a member of the EU. It does not pool sovereignty. We can compare Japan to the UK to see the difference.

Currently the US is pressuring Japan to reduce tariffs on US beef imports. Japan is trying to resist. It was hoping to pool sovereignty with a multilateral trade deal involving other nations in the region, but the US pulled out because each country is less able to resist its demands on their own.

The US has also indicated that if the UK leaves the EU it would be looking to do a similar trade deal involving beef. The EU is large enough to easily resist the US in this regard, but the UK on its own may well not be. In fact, the "offer" from the US has been cited as something the UK can accept after leaving to make up for lost trade with the EU.

So in this case pooled sovereignty, being part of the larger EU democratic system gives the UK more sovereignty, a greater ability to freely decide what kind of beef tariffs it wants even in the face of powerful nations putting pressure on it.

Comment: A valuable point as well although it looks mainly at the perspective of why pooled sovereignty rather than what it is.

Comment: I like the example, but I am quite sure that some would disagree that "being part of the larger EU democratic system gives the UK more sovereignty."

Comment: @phoog they are wrong

Comment: Well that settles it then.  Why don't you go tell them they've got it backwards so they can stop trying to leave the EU.  In fact, you're confusing bargaining power with sovereignty.  Membership in the EU brings the power of collective bargaining at a cost of *reduced* sovereignty, because a member state can no longer unilaterally decide on its beef tariffs; it must come to an agreement with the other member states.

Comment: @phoog I've been trying to tell them, they seem hell bent on throwing it away.

Comment: @phoog Your argument contains an obvious flaw. Outside the EU a country can't unilaterally decide its own beef tariffs either. There are WTO rules, and trade deals where such things must be traded. For example, the UK is unlikely to get a good deal from Trump if it insists on high tariffs on US beef, or maintains the ban on it.

Comment: Not being able to do something because your negotiating partner or trading partner won't like it isn't a restriction on sovereignty.  Not being able to develop an independent negotiating strategy, however, is.  And the fact that joining the WTO entails a (sovereign) decision by a country to restrict its freedom of action (and therefore partially relinquish its sovereignty) doesn't imply that joining the EU doesn't entail a similar (and greater) voluntary relinquishing of sovereignty.  It does.

Comment: @phoog I don't think you understand the basic concept of trade deals. The fundamental exchange is a little bit of sovereignty in exchange for the removal of trade barriers. It's like how when you get a job you trade a little bit of freedom to do what you like all day for money.

Comment: *It's like how when you get a job you trade a little bit of freedom to do what you like all day for money:* And unionized workers have even less freedom, since they cannot negotiate independently with their employers, and must strike if the union instructs them to.

Comment: @phoog unions are a great example of how pooled sovereignty results in a stronger negotiating position and ultimately better terms. Alone an individual worker has little leverage.

Comment: Precisely.  Just as an employment contract or trade deal represents a reduction in freedom or sovereignty in exchange for a benefit, membership in a union brings a greater benefit in exchange for a greater reduction in freedom or sovereignty.

Comment: How is getting what you want by joining with like minded people a reduction of sovereignty? You have a voice in that organisation. The alternative is having no day at all because you have no power as an individual against a powerful employer.